# python running chromedriver doesnt launch browser on cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

under cygwin, when I run try to run selenium webdriver, python starts a second process, and then proceeds to halt on instantiation. I notice if I close one of the two processes via the windows task manager, the browser then starts and navigates to the directory.

stripping down python to only selenium does not appear to make any differences.

here are the libraries installed,

```
$ pip3.6 freeze
selenium==3.141.0
urllib3==1.25.7
```

and here is the sample code.

```
import time;
import sys;
from selenium import webdriver;

print("here0");
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print("here1");
driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
print("here2");
time.sleep(20);
```

when I cancel it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1318, in _execute_child
    part = os.read(errpipe_read, 50000)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was determined to be a bug, and will be fixed in the next patch

> 2) steps to reproduce python selenium.
>   - Run set, select emacs, python 3.5,6 or 7 and associated dev tools.
>   - install.
>   - from prompt:
>   - python -m ensurepip --default-pip
>   -pip3.6 install selenium
>   "
>   pip3.6 freeze
>   selenium==3.141.0
>   urllib3==1.25.7
>   "
>   Sample python test code.
>   from selenium import webdriver
>
> EXE_PATH = r'/cygdrive/c/webdriver/chromedriver.exe';
>
> ## driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH)
>
> ## driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=run.log"])
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=run.log"])
>   driver.get('https://google.com')
>   - at this point, the program will hang. It looks like its waiting to connect to chromedriver. 
>   running task manager on windows 10, will yield two python3.x processes. This may be expected behavior, I presume its opened with a fork and the child process socket is not closed. Closing the child causes the main to run, cutting the main breaks execution. This appears to be a problem with any python 3.x installation I have done.
>
> Cancelling via ctrl-c yields the following:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 20, in 
>   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
>   self.service.start()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
>   stdin=PIPE)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in **init**
>   restore_signals, start_new_session)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1318, in _execute_child
>   part = os.read(errpipe_read, 50000)
>   KeyboardInterrupt

Thanks for the report.

I could not reproduce the problem 1).

As for the problem 2), it seems to be the same problem with
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2020-01/msg00093.html.

I already submitted a patch for that issue:
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2020-q1/msg00010.html.

I confirmed the problem 2) is fixed with this patch.

Please wait for the new cygwin release.

--